# Google Adwords adding Negative Keywords with special Characters via API

Tags: c#, google-api, google-ads-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to add a Negative keyword via the `CampaignCriterionService`, of a Keyword that was retrieved from the SearchTerms Report for a specific Campaign.

I have working code that adds Negative keywords to a Campaign, great. The problem comes from where the Keyword text contains a "special character" ([see here](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/7476658?hl=en&visit_id=1-636592100897440761-3585971896&rd=1#symbol))

**error:**

> Keyword text has invalid characters or symbols.. (Error: CriterionError.KEYWORD_HAS_INVALID_CHARS, FieldPath: operations[0].operand.criterion.text, Trigger: plain mirror 100 * 60)

I pulled the keyword from the Search Term report it has a Keyword Id. Therefore I tried to add the keyword as a negative, using the KeywordId using the below

**example:**

```
    using Google.Api.Ads.AdWords.Lib;
    using Google.Api.Ads.AdWords.Util.Reports.v201802;
    using Google.Api.Ads.AdWords.v201802;

     [TestMethod]
        public void AddSingleNegativeKeywordToCampaign()
        {
            GoogleAdwords.Model.Campaign campaign = new GoogleAdwords.Model.Campaign(CampaignID);
            List<Keyword> keywords = new List<Keyword> { new Keyword { id = 27736878000, matchType = KeywordMatchType.EXACT } };
            campaign.AddNegativeKeywordstoCampaign(keywords);
        }

        public class Campaign : AdwordsBase
    {

        public long CampaignId { get; set; }
        public string CampaignName;
        
        public Campaign(long campaignId) : base()
        {
            CampaignId = campaignId;
        }
        
   public void AddNegativeKeywordstoCampaign(List<Keyword> ListofKeywords)
        {
            AddKeywordstoCampaign(ListofKeywords, Operator.ADD);
        }

        
    private void AddKeywordstoCampaign(List<Keyword> keywords, Operator @operator)
        {
            using (CampaignCriterionService campaignCriterionService =
          (CampaignCriterionService)user.GetService(
              AdWordsService.v201802.CampaignCriterionService))
            {

                List<CampaignCriterionOperation> operations = new List<CampaignCriterionOperation>();

                foreach (Keyword keyword in keywords)
                {
                    // Create the biddable ad group criterion.
                    NegativeCampaignCriterion keywordCriterion = new NegativeCampaignCriterion();
                    keywordCriterion.campaignId = CampaignId;
                    keywordCriterion.criterion = keyword;

                    // Create the operations.
                    CampaignCriterionOperation operation = new CampaignCriterionOperation();
                    operation.@operator = @operator;
                    operation.operand = keywordCriterion;

                    operations.Add(operation);
                }
                try
                {
                    // Create the keywords.
                    CampaignCriterionReturnValue retVal = campaignCriterionService.mutate(
                        operations.ToArray());

                    // Display the results.
                    if (retVal != null && retVal.value != null)
                    {
                        foreach (CampaignCriterion campaignCriterion in retVal.value)
                        {
                            // If you are adding multiple type of criteria, then you may need to
                            // check for
                            //
                            // if (adGroupCriterion is Keyword) { ... }
                            //
                            // to identify the criterion type.
                            Debug.WriteLine("Keyword with Campaign id = '{0}', keyword id = '{1}', text = " +
                                "'{2}' and match type = '{3}' was {4}.", campaignCriterion.campaignId,
                                campaignCriterion.criterion.id, (campaignCriterion.criterion as Keyword).text,
                                (campaignCriterion.criterion as Keyword).matchType, @operator.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("No keywords were added.");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw new System.ApplicationException("Failed to create keywords.", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

BUT this doesn't work as the api reports the error:

> Missing required field.. (Error: RequiredError.REQUIRED, FieldPath: operations[0].operand.criterion.text, Trigger: )

### My question is

I can add the search term as a Negative in the Adwords UI, so, therefore, it must be possible. has anybody been able to achieve this using the most recent version of the Adwords API? (v201802)

to be perfectly clear, i don't think there is anything wrong with the code as such, its more of a question about how to add keywords that fall into this remit.

Comment: I wasn't able to add "plain mirror 100 * 60" as a negative keyword in the UI, neither directly to a campaign nor to a negative keyword list. Error is always **"Keywords cannot contain non-standard characters like: ! @ % , *"**. Does this actually work for you?

Comment: apologies, i thought i could, but it seems that in actual fact i was not able to.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that, true to the documentation [here](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/7476658?hl=en&visit_id=1-636592100897440761-3585971896&rd=1#symbol) special characters cannot be added to a campaign though any medium.